# SOGo Webmail font customisation

Tags: fonts, webmail, customising

I would like to be able to customise the font, and other formatting when writing an email in the SOGo system. We had this setting, but lost it somehow while dealing with other settings.

How can I access to that panel that lets me customise the email I'm sendig?

I tried looking for a setting in the settings menu under all of the menu points. I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Settings > Mail > Message format > HTML